# Only 10 documents are inserted in elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, mapreduce

I am inserting to elasticsearch using mapreduce.

below is mycode:

```
public class CreditBreauDriver extends Configured implements Tool
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new CreditBreauDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreditBreauDriver.class);

        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
        logger.debug("Entering MRInputDriver.run()");
        if (args.length != 2) 
        {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n",getClass().getSimpleName());
            ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
            return -1;
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(CreditBreauDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("Elastic-Test");     
        logger.info("Input path " + args[0]);        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));        
        Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
        conf.set("es.nodes","http://192.168.63.128:9200");
        conf.set("es.resource","es/credit");
        //conf.set("es.mapping.id", "_id");          
        job.setMapperClass(CreditBureauMapper.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(EsOutputFormat.class); 
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(MapWritable.class);
        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;
        System.out.println("job.isSuccessful " + job.isSuccessful());
        logger.debug("Exiting MRInputDriver.run()");
        return returnValue;
        }
}
```

And this is my mapper program:

```
public class CreditBureauMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, MapWritable> {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreditBureauMapper.class);

    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        logger.debug("Entering WordCountMapper.map() " + this);
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");

        MapWritable mapWritable = new MapWritable();
        //mapWritable.put(new Text("_id"), new Text(splittedLine[0]));
        //mapWritable.put(new Text(splittedLine[0]), new Text(splittedLine[1]+","+splittedLine[2]+","+splittedLine[3]));
        mapWritable.put(new Text("doc_id"), new Text(splittedLine[0]));
        mapWritable.put(new Text("content"), new Text(splittedLine[1]+","+splittedLine[2]+","+splittedLine[3]));
        context.write(value, mapWritable);
        logger.debug("Exiting WordCountMapper"+value);
    }

}
```

My input data has around 100 rows but only 10 rows are getting inserted.
Note:Data are different.
Do I need to change some property.  This is single node elasticsearch in my local VM

Comment: How do you know that only 10 rows are inserted? A GET /index/_search only returns 10 rows by default. What does /index/_count return?

Comment: Ok....yes..count gives me all record..how can I see all records??

Comment: POST /index/_search with body: '{ "size": 100}' - You cannot get 'all' results, you have to specify a size.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch will only give you the amout of results you ask for with the size parameter, if you don't set it it defaults to 10. It will tell you the total number of documents matching your query in hits.totalhits.

If you know you will have no more than, for example 475 documents, you could set size to 500, and get them all. Of course this would stop working if you ever exceded what you'd set as your size, and if you were expecting to get a great many documents, maybe a few thousand, this would become highly impractical.

The best way to get all the documents is to get them in batches using a scan and scroll search, though this is a bit more involved and complicated.
[This page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) of elasticsearch's documentation explains how to do it via CURL.